# Как отобразить название файла в label?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как из компонента `listBox` отобразить имя автора музыки в `label1`, а название композиции `label2`? Пользователь нажимает `button` который воспроизводит композицию, тогда и должно отобразиться имя и название в `label1` и `label2`.

Comment: Можно использовать `.Split(" - ")` в `string`.
[Подробнее на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Автор1 - Песня1" );
        listBox1.Items.Add("Автор2 - Песня2");
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as ListBox;
        string Autor = s.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string[] substrings = Autor.Split('-');

        label1.Text = substrings[0];
        label2.Text = substrings[1];

    }
```

Результат : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если менять label нужно именно при щелчке по кнопке то можно сделать так:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as ListBox;
        string AutorSong = s.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string[] substrings = AutorSong.Split('-');
        Autor = substrings[0];
        Song = substrings[1];
    }
    string Autor;
    string Song;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Autor;
        label2.Text = Song;
        // воспроизведение и(или) другие операции

    }
```

Comment: Сначала не дошло. Все работает, спасибо.

Comment: А что если меняться название в label должно когда я нажму button который воспроизводит трек, а не просто когда я выделаю трек в listBox?

Comment: @River Можете объявить 2 глобальные переменные и записать в них автора песни и название а при щелчке по кнопке присваивать вашим Label текст из этих переменных.

Comment: Еще вопрос. Когда появляется название трека в label2, то в конце есть точка и формат .mp3. Как убрать это?

Comment: @River например так  -    label2.Text = Song.Replace(".mp3","");

Comment: или через Trim ::: `char[] trim = { '.', 'm', 'p', '3' };
            label2.Text = Song.Trim(trim);`